# Como compilar una variable de texto C# a un executable

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

He estado probando CodeDom y Roslyn pero ninguno realmente me funciono, hay algun comando o libreria que compilase una variable string a un .exe?
ej: string Code = "using System; \n Console.ReadLine();"
y si habria algunas que funcionasen en .net 8.0 o 7.0

Comment: A ver si entiendo, ¿quieres compilar un input? ¿Cuál es el escenario? Entre mejor detalles, más chances de obtener respuesta, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 + https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Hola, estoy haciendo un programa en donde el usuario ingresa palabras claves y el programa lo traduce a C# para luego compilarlos, el programa crea el codigo usando solamente funciones basicas como Console.WriteLine y Console.ReadLine.

Comment: no, no podes ejecutar variables, no hay nada que lo haga dentro de .net...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score -1):

Explico:
En mi proyecto estaba creando un sistema en el que el usuario escribia por ejemplo "Imprimir" y si era igual a "Imprimir" guardaba "Console.WriteLine("Hola");" en una variable, el proyecto lo hice en visual studio code junto al paquete NuGet de CodeDom (una libreria que permite compilar codigo C# en assembly), pero la cosa es que no funcionaba, buscando mas respuestas parece que no era compatible con mi plataforma, entonces luego de tratar muchas soluciones publique aqui mi pregunta sobre alguna libreria similar que fuese compatible, luego de eso instale visual studio comunity 2022 con .NET Framework 4.8.1 (que tiene incluido CodeDom) y cree un proyecto con plantilla Roslyn, luego de eso el mismo codigo que probe en visual studio code funciono perfecto ahi.
En resumen, en vez de descargar CodeDom por NuGet, lo descarge junto al framework y visual studio comunity y funciono

Comment: Y tambien si aun les da el error de que no es compatible con la plataforma entonces descargen como paquete individial en visual studio el .net compiler platform sdk

Comment: Roslyn es el nombre clave del compilador on the fly... y no es el mismo que usa vs code... o sea, no creas cosas con roslyn... y de paso, seguro, tu problema fue que ese paquete no era compatible con tu framework....